How to compile the value of the result which I am getting in list into a single one
the code that I am getting the above result for
the problem I am facing is that I want the output to give me the value of the fibonacci sequence in a list, is there a better way to do this, if not, how do i get the program to give me the output in a single list?
I tried many things, first as seen above i tried assigning a value x for the "for loop", then instead of defining x as list(str(fib(i))) i just defined it as fib(i) and consecutively gave the values y and z as the str(x) and list(y) respectively, but the list just gives me the value of fib(n) inside the list

When posting a question with code, please don't use images, but put the code in a code block. Images are not appreciated for code and error messages. Please edit your question to replace the image by the actual code.

Why not use append()?Then use print(list) directly.

but what exactly and how do i append this, since there is only one def function providing the list. Sorry im new to programming and doing this for the first time
